# In SQL Server, how to find number of rows in a table without doing a count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table named **punch** with lot of rows. I want to know number of rows in this table but without doing a `count`. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Thanks

Comment: why would you not want to use `count`?

Comment: @vkp `count` is taking lot of time. I ran it and it was still not completed after 8 minutes so I killed it. There must be another easier way.

Comment: Are there any transactions with locks on `punch` that might have your query on hold?

Comment: @BaconBits might be the lock issue. this time i issued `count` with `(nolock)` and get the response in 2 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql have a function for that

```
sp_spaceused <Tablename>;
```

[image]

Comment: this tells me 204137424 rows in **punch** table

Comment: and what is the correct number or rows for punch?

Comment: size of **punch**? I dont understand. Please explain.

Comment: how many rows you get if do `select count(*) from punch`

Comment: 204137424 rows I get

Comment: Then you are getting the right value isnt? what is the problem? isnt fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
select row_count
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id = object_id('punch')
```

Comment: this gives me 9 rows. Do I need to add all the values in those 9 rows to know the total number of rows in that table?

Comment: Yes that view gives you the row count for every partition in the table. It is very clearly stated right there in the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187737.aspx

Comment: The values I get are 72215111,
131922313,
204137424,
72215111,
131922313,
72215111,
131922313,
72215111,
131922313. If I add them up the total is **1020687120**.

Comment: This should be filtered by correct index_id